# How to combine two array using ramda library?

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I have two array as below

```
const l1 = [ {"a": 1, "a1": 2}, {"b": 3, "b1": 4}, {"c": 5, "c1": 6} ];
const l2 = [ {"d": 2}, {"e": 2}, {"f": 2} ];
```

How can I use ramda library to combine these two and get result like

```
[ {"a": 1, "a1": 2, "d": 2}, {"a": 1, "a1": 2, "e": 2}, {"a": 1, "a1": 2, "f": 2}, 
{"b": 3, "b1": 4, "d": 2}, {"b": 3, "b1": 4, "e": 2}, {"b": 3, "b1": 4, "f": 2}, 
{"c": 5, "c1": 6, "d": 2}, {"c": 5, "c1": 6, "e": 2}, {"c": 5, "c1": 6, "f": 2} ]
```

I used

```
R.map(R.xprod(__, l2, l1)
```

But not working since i got object inside array.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get a Cartesian product of two arrays of objects you can create a function by lifting merge:

```js
const fn = R.lift(R.merge)

const l1 = [ {"a": 1, "a1": 2}, {"b": 3, "b1": 4}, {"c": 5, "c1": 6} ];
const l2 = [ {"d": 2}, {"e": 2}, {"f": 2} ];

const result = fn(l1, l2)

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.0/ramda.js" integrity="sha256-buL0byPvI/XRDFscnSc/e0q+sLA65O9y+rbF+0O/4FE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: I love the elegance of `lift`!  This is much cleaner than my first thought: `pipe (xprod, map (apply (merge)))`.

Comment: I still struggle with R.lift, but this seems like a classic case. That was actually my 2nd thought - `pipe(xprod, map(mergeAll))`.

Comment: `lift`, `ap`, and `chain` are so powerful, but I don't always think to use them when I should.  (And yes, obviously `mergeAll` would have been better than `apply(merge)`; neither is close to as nice as the `lift` solution, thought.)

Answer (score 1):

With plain Javascript, you could take *cartesian product* with a double nested reduce by mapping new objects.

This approach works for an arbirary count of arrays (sort of ...).

```js
const
    l1 = [{ a: 1, a1: 2 }, { b: 3, b1: 4 }, { c: 5, c1: 6 }],
    l2 = [{ d: 2 }, { e: 2 }, { f: 2 }],
    result = [l1, l2].reduce((a, b) => a.reduce((r, v) => r.concat(b.map(w => ({ ...v, ...w }))), []));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Why "sort of"? I haven't tested, but it looks as though it would work.

Answer (score 1):

If not very particular about ramda, you can do as below with one line using `flatMap` and `map`.

```js
const l1 = [
  { a: 1, a1: 2 },
  { b: 3, b1: 4 },
  { c: 5, c1: 6 }
];
const l2 = [{ d: 2 }, { e: 2 }, { f: 2 }];

const merged = l2.flatMap(item2 => l1.map(item1 => ({ ...item1, ...item2 })));
console.log(JSON.stringify(merged));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another option to merge arrays using R.reduce function

```
const input = {
  arr1: ['a', 'b'],
  arr2: ['c', 'd']
}

R.compose(
  R.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    return [...acc, ...cur]
  }, []),
  R.map(([key, value]) => value),
  R.toPairs
)(input)
```